# iphone 5 hangs when connected to MBP as an Audio Input Device

Tags: iphone, audio, midi

Connecting my iphone 5C to my MBP 17 early 2011, macOS HighSerra 10.13.6, with a Lightning cable to USB, opening Audio MIDI Setup I can see the device. The moment I enabled it, it hangs with a spinning wheel. But it worked once, two days ago !

Before: ￼

[image: Before connection]

After:

[image: After connection]

P.S.: after contacting Apple Support and making a Remote Diagnose on my iphone, they think it is my battery ("just" 64%).I disagree.